# How do you do border detection in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

My application need to do something when the cursor is hovering on the edge of a path or a rect or someothers (only on the edge not the object),but I can't find any api to do it. How to achieve it? thanks .

For example the pseudo code below

```
path.on('mouse:move', function () {
          if(  mouse on the edge of the path ){
             change the cursor to a star
          }else{
             do nothing
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting the **perPixelTargetFind** property of the object to true.
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html#perPixelTargetFind

```
path.perPixelTargetFind = true;
```

That way you could:

```
canvas.on({
    "mouse:over": (event) => {
        if (event.target == path) {
            change cursor;
        }
        else {
            do nothing;
        }
    }
});
```

The only downside is that this will also fire when the mouse is over object fill, so technically if you wanted to do only border detection you might have to remove any fill from the object.

```
var pathFill = path.fill;
path.fill = "transparent";
```

And then if you wanted to reset everything after the mouse is no longer hovering on the edge, you might:

```
canvas.on({
    "mouse:out": (event) => {
        if (event.target == path) {
            reset cursor;
            path.fill = pathFill;
        }
        else {
            do nothing;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, this will loss the  event listen of fill part. I asked a similar question on  konvas and got a good way to deal with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230257/how-to-do-mouse-hit-testing-on-the-edge-border-stroked-part-of-a-shape