# How to do mouse hit testing on the edge / border / stroked part of a shape

Tags: javascript, konvajs

In my application,  I need to detect the mouse events on the edge / border / stroked part of a shape - but not on the filled part. I have not found a way to do this.

I do not know how to get started with this but here is pseudo code of what I am trying to do.

```
shape.on('mousemove', function () {
          if (mouse on the edge of the shape) {
             // change the cursor to a star
          } else {
            // do nothing
          }
        });
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect mouse hits on the edge of a shape only, use the [fillEnabled:false](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Shape.html#fillEnabled) property. What this does is tell Konva to disregard fill - meaning that any event-listening on the fill-part of the shape will be switched off. However, with great power great responsibility comes and the fillEnabled property also stops any visual fill you might want to appear.

Putting that together, if you want to hit-test the stroke part of a shape only you will need another transparent shape drawn on top of the visual shape to detect mouse events.

As a bonus, you can use the [hitStrokeWidth](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Shape.html#hitStrokeWidth) property to make the hit-detecting region of the stroke wider - as if you set the stroke 'thicker' for purposes of mouse detection.

Snippet below shows this approach on a rect and random polygon.

```js
// Set up a stage
stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  }),

  // add a layer to draw on
  layer = new Konva.Layer(),

  rect = new Konva.Rect({
    name: 'r1',
    x: 220,
    y: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    stroke: 'cyan',
    fill: 'transparent',
    fillEnabled: false
  }),
  poly = new Konva.Line({
    points: [23, 20, 23, 160, 70, 93, 150, 109, 290, 139, 270, 93],
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    closed: true,
    fillEnabled: false,
    hitStrokeWidth: 10
  });


// Add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);
layer.add(rect, poly)

stage.draw();

rect.on('mouseover', function() {
  $('#info').html('Rect MouseEnter')
})

rect.on('mouseout', function() {
  $('#info').html('Rect mouseOut')
})

poly.on('mouseover', function() {
  $('#info').html('Poly MouseEnter')
})

poly.on('mouseout', function() {
  $('#info').html('Poly mouseOut')
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^3/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>Move mouse over the shapes </p>
<p id='info'>Events show here</p>
<div id="container"></div>
```

It is easy to clone a shape to make an edge-event detecting version and place the clone over the original shape so that you can detect the edge-events specifically. See the following working snippet - enable the console to view the events sequence.

```js
// Set up a stage
stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  }),

  // add a layer to draw on
  layer = new Konva.Layer(),

  rect = new Konva.Rect({
    name: 'r1',
    x: 220,
    y: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    stroke: 'cyan',
    fill: 'magenta'
  }),
  poly = new Konva.Line({
    points: [23, 20, 23, 160, 70, 93, 150, 109, 290, 139, 270, 93],
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    closed: true,
    hitStrokeWidth: 10
  }),

  // this is a clone of rect with fillEnabled set to false, placed 'above' rect in the z-order. 
  rect2 = rect.clone({
    fillEnabled: false
  }),
  poly2 = poly.clone({
    fillEnabled: false
  }),



  // Add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
layer.add(rect, rect2, poly, poly2)

stage.draw();

rect.on('mouseover', function() {
  showMsg('Rect MouseEnter');
})

rect2.on('mouseover', function() {
  showMsg('Rect2 Edge MouseEnter');
})

rect2.on('mouseout', function() {
  showMsg('Rect2 Edge mouseOut');
})

poly.on('mouseover', function() {
  showMsg('Poly MouseEnter');
})

poly.on('mouseout', function() {
  showMsg('Poly MouseOut');
})

poly2.on('mouseover', function() {
  showMsg('Poly2 Edge MouseEnter');
})

poly2.on('mouseout', function() {
  showMsg('Poly2 Edge MouseOut');
})

function showMsg(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
  $('#info').html(msg)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^3/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>Move mouse over the shapes </p>
<p id='info'>Events show here</p>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,as you say ,this will lost any event-listening on the fill-part,finaly, I found a approximate way ,not elegant but it worked for me.I  post it below

Comment: If you use two objects stacked so that the edge-detect with no-fill is over the visual object that has fill, then the visual object can still be listening for mouseover on its fill section.

Comment: I modified the answer below to show how to clone any shape and stack the clone over the original shape, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a precise approach ,just a approximate way which detect if the cursor just near the out edge of the object.

```
stage.on('mousemove', function (e) {

        var deta = 3;

        var node8 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX, y: e.evt.clientY});
        if(node8){
            console.log(node8.getClassName()+"====mouse on object=====");
            return;
        }

        var node = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX+deta, y: e.evt.clientY});
        if(node){
            console.log(node.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }
        var  node1 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX, y: e.evt.clientY+deta});
        if(node1){
            console.log(node1.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }
        var  node2 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX+deta, y: e.evt.clientY+deta});
        if(node2){
            console.log(node2.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }
        var node3 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX-deta, y: e.evt.clientY});
        if(node3){
            console.log(node3.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }
        var node4 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX, y: e.evt.clientY-deta});
        if(node4){
            console.log(node4.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }
        var node5 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX-deta, y: e.evt.clientY-deta});
        if(node5){
            console.log(node5.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }

        var node6 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX-deta, y: e.evt.clientY+deta});
        if(node6){
            console.log(node6.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }

        var node7 = stage.getIntersection({x: e.evt.clientX+deta, y: e.evt.clientY-deta});
        if(node7){
            console.log(node7.getClassName()+"====mouse on edge=====");
            return;
        }

      });
```

Comment: This approximation could work, but it is also easy to clone a shape and stack the clone over the original to give a very accurate way to handling edge hit detection that requires no approximation.